# RxSwift on UITextview

Tags: swift, uitextview, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I want to call a function every 4 changes in my textview.
how can I perform it with RXswift debounce throttle?
I use UITextViewDelegate to detect changes in my textview.

Answer (score 2):

I use rx.net and one way of achieving that is by using `buffer`

After looking at RxSwift's implementation of `buffer`

```
func buffer(timeSpan:count:scheduler:)
```

You have 2 parameters:

- `timeSpan` as the timeout
- `count` to specify the buffer's max elements

The window is returned every time either the timeout happens or the max count is reached.

So, in your case, just set the timeout to 10 years or something, and set count to 4. Take the last element of each window returned.

After importing `RxSwift` and `RxCocoa` you can do:

```
textView
    .rx
    .text
    .buffer(timeSpan: 3600, count: 4, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { (buffer) in
        guard let lastestString = buffer.last as? String else { return }
        print(lastestString)
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

NOTE: `disposeBag` is declared globally for the above example.

Comment: when I write "textview.rx." the only suggestion is "base" and after that I can use textview's delegate methods. I know how to use throttle for button tap, but using it on a textview's changes is unclear to me.

Comment: @babak If the only suggestion after `.rx` is `base` then you need to `import RxCocoa` in order to access the reactive elements on Cocoa elements such as a `UITextView`. After that you will get more suggestions and in your particular case, you should be subscribing to `rx.text` e.g. `textView.rx.text`

Comment: @Sentinel `.buffer` doesn't seem to work. OP wants to be notified after every 4 character updates in a `textView`. `debounce` and `buffer` are both time based, not change based.

Comment: @staticVoidMan Yeah I would have to look into rxswift, I use rx.net, and buffer has an overload based on count or time or some combo of both.

Comment: @staticVoidMan Actually I checked and no, buffer in rxswift allows element count. Buffer ought to solve the problem easily. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observables/Buffer.swift

Comment: @babak Check the .buffer operator in link above.

Comment: @Sentinel I don't see an overload on RxSwift's `buffer`. I see one function `buffer(timeSpan:count:scheduler:)` that has a `count` parameter but that is just to specify the maximum elements in the buffer. It still seems to be time-based as there is a `timeSpan` parameter which if it were 1 second then every second it could give a max of 4 elements. In case there are no changes, it gives an empty array every second.

Comment: @staticVoidMan Sure but OP could set timespan to 10 years and set count to 4 and it should return a list of 4 items every time 4 elements changed. Right? Actually I just checked the code, and that's what it does. Same as in .NET.

Comment: @Sentinel Interesting. Let me have a look. I just found this question very interesting so don't mind me.

Comment: @staticVoidMan No problems man, it's line 97. Basically buffer allows you to buffer for a certain number and/or until timeout.

Comment: @Sentinel So the concept of whichever happens first; either `timeSpan` or `count`. If `count` then buffer has all the last 4 changes. If `timeSpan` then whatever is in the buffer so far. Tried it and it works. Can I update your answer with the code?

Comment: @staticVoidMan Sure, go ahead. And upvote the answer :-)

Comment: @Sentinel yes, the problem was I was importing RxSwift, but RxCocoa needed to be used. Thank you very much

Comment: @babak Sounds delicious but I have to stick with my Rx.net  creds to StaticVoidMan for the cocoa stuff.

Answer (score 0):

RxSwift 5.0 tested

```
        textField.rx
        .text
        .orEmpty
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .map { _ in 1}
        .scan(0, accumulator: { $0 + $1 })
        .filter { $0 % 4 == 0 }
        .subscribe(onNext: { (value) in
            print(value)
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

you can change number 4 to 10 if you would like to achieve firing event every 10 element.Good Luck.